# Cross-domain Exchange Mailbox move within same Exchange Org

Tags: exchange

Theoretical question.

We have two Domains, `DomainA.local` and `DomainB.local`, with Exchange Mbx servers within each (within the same Exchange organisation). `DomainB` is a `child domain` of `DomainA`.

The goal is to move a mailbox from Exchange Mbx in DomainB, to Exchange Mbx in DomainA, while connecting it to a new account in DomainA (thus disconnecting from the account in DomainB)

Is this possible? What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally if you disconnect a mailbox from an AD user account the mailbox is not directly deleted (depending on your configuration it is stored for e.g. 14 days on your Exchange environment). So you could disconnect the mailbox:

> [Disable-Mailbox](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997210(v=exchg.160).aspx) -Identity "John Woods"

and then connect that to another AD account:

> [Connect-Mailbox](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123490(v=exchg.141).aspx) -Identity "John Evans" -Database "MBXDB02" -User
>   "John Evans"

What remains here is if the users can access the other exchange server. But you might wish to move the mailbox then to the correct server.